# update value document ID firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to update a document value from a collection in Firestore. I have the following that works for me but only for an ID document. But if I have a thousand records how do I update them? How do I get the document ID automatically?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ea3wme

What I need is that every time I click on the `update` button the value of the`state` column (of that row) changes to `false`.

[image]

**myService.ts**

```
updateEstado(){
  this.afs.doc('domiciliarios/OI4GXrNTLncFQpaXajdy').update({
    estado : false
  });
}
```

**myComponent.ts**

```
actualizarEstado(){
  this.fs.updateEstado();
}
```

**myComponent.html**

```
<td>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" (click)="actualizarEstado()">Editar</button>
</td>
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to iterate all the documents in the collection and make a change to all of them?

Comment: not for everyone, but for each specific document

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "not for everyone".

Comment: I think I did not express myself well, I did a satckblitz please look: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ea3wme What I need is that every time I click on the `update` button the value of the `Estado` column (of that row) changes to `false`. He let me understand?

Answer (score 2):

Your button should send the key when calling the function just like this:-

**myComponent.html**

```
<td>
   <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" (click)="actualizarEstado(domiciliario.id)">Update</button>
</td>
```

**myComponent.ts**

```
actualizarEstado(key){
    this.fs.updateEstado(key);
}
```

**myService.ts**

```
updateEstado(key){
    this.afs.doc('domiciliarios/' + key).update({
      estado : false
    })
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, I'll mark it as the correct answer. An additional query How can I iterate so that it changes to `true` if the default value is `false` and vice versa? I'm trying an `if / else` `if (estado = true) {estado: false;}, else: {status: true}` but it marks me an error.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I've checked on Stackblitz that you already found a solution for this.